# fread buffer size - I've loads of memory so why not make it huge?

Tags: c, memory, buffer, fread

Ok I haven`t the benefit of having studied computer science so this may be an easy question to those that have. 
Basically as the title says What is stopping me from creating a massive buffer, much bigger than the file size to use with the fread() function. 
As I understand it fread() will return the total number of elements successfully read so at that point I could just realloc the buffer back to the file size.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main () {
    FILE * pFile;
    long lSize;
    char * buffer = NULL;
    size_t result = 0;
    pFile = fopen ( "test.txt" , "r" );
    if (pFile==NULL) {fputs ("File error",stderr); exit (1);}

// memory is cheap!! size:
    lSize = 1000000;
    buffer = (char*) realloc(buffer, (sizeof(char) * lSize));
    if (buffer)
    {
        result += fread(buffer, sizeof(char), 1, pFile);
    }
// copy the file into the buffer:
    result = fread (buffer,1,lSize,pFile);

/* file is now loaded in the memory buffer. Now resize buffer    */
    buffer = (char*) realloc(buffer, (sizeof(char) * result));

// tidy up
    printf("\n%s",buffer);
    free(buffer);
    fclose (pFile);
    return 0;
 }
```

This is just a sample of what I'm talking about. I'm presuming that the file size is < buffer size

Comment: Essentially, nothing.  In fact, why bother to realloc it?

Comment: Well Just to free up memory for the next file, basically as it stands i can grab all the available memory load myfile and then realloc to free back up that memory. I suppose what i`d really like to know is this form of greedy programming the correct way to go?

Comment: buffer is just a buffer, you can choose how you want to allocate it. Normally you would use a reasonable value. Why use a huge value? There is clearly no benefit.

Comment: @Shauny OK, if the app is going to open more files, sure.  Your example app only opened one.

Comment: @terencehill there clearly is.  If you can avoid realloc calls, you avoid the memory allocation and the potential bulk data copy.

Comment: @terence   The benefit is I can read in the whole file in one call, no looping and reallocing memory.

Comment: @MartinJames I never said  to use less memory than you need. Normally you have an idea of the value you need: if you start with that reasonable value, which means enough to load it in memory and not too much that you have to reduce it, you don't need to call realloc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the whole objective is speed, then allocating a giant buffer and reading the file with one `fread` into it and then just do the processor-intensive thing, then the approach is fine.

```
int main (void) {
    FILE *pFile;
    char *buffer;
    size_t result;
    struct stat statbuf;

    if (!stat("test.txt", &statbuf)
    ||  !(pFile = fopen("test.txt", "r")) {fputs ("File error", stderr); return (1);}

    // memory is cheap!!
    if ((buffer= malloc(statbuf.st_size)==0) {fputs ("Memory error", stderr); return (1);}
    result= fread(buffer, 1, lSize, pFile);
    fclose (pFile);
    if (result != statbuf.st_size) {fputs ("Read error", stderr); return (1);}}

    // now use lots of cycles...

    free(buffer);
    return 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Because it makes more sense to have just as much memory as you need. What's the point of allocating, say, 2k B of heap, when your file could be just 5 bytes? It makes more sense to reallocate memory only when needed.

```
#define INITALLOC     16
#define STEP           8
typedef long ssize_t;

ssize_t readfile(FILE *fp, char *dynbuf)
{
    size_t nalloced, n;
    int c;
    char *tmp;

    if ((dynbuf = malloc(INITALLOC)) == NULL)
        return -1;
    nalloced = INITALLOC;

    for (n = 0; (c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF; dynbuf[n++] = c)
        if (n == nalloced) {
            if ((tmp = realloc(dynbuf, nalloced += STEP) != NULL)
                dynbuf = tmp;
            else
                return -1;
        }
    return n;
}
```

Comment: 'It makes more sense to reallocate memory only when needed.' - OK, so if you allocate a huge buffer to start with, you may well not need to reallocate at all.

Comment: @MartinJames but allocating too much wastes memory.

Comment: thats what i did @terencehill

Comment: Sorry!!! My bad, did you edited it or I was really blind? Removed the wrong comment

Comment: @terencehill i think you commented as soon as i edited it, and pressed the edit button

Comment: @stackptr if it's virtual memory, and you have no other use for the space, why worry?  Put it another way - how many SO posts do you see with accidental buffer overflows, (lots)?  How many do you see with memory alloc fails due to oversize buffers, (find one:).

Comment: @MartinJames well to avoid accidental buffer overflows, I used realloc as soon as my buffer filled up. My solution is best, because there is no chance for buffer overflows, but at the same time, I don't allocate too much memory. Only as much as I need, maybe a little more. The only problem is that `realloc` is slower.

Comment: Also, given the need to read a 5-byte string, devs. persist in allocating 5 bytes, so having the null-terminator written out-of-bounds.  There are dozens of such posts.  If the devs. could somehow be persuaded that allocating less than, (say), 128 bytes is illegal, we would have fewer SO posts.

Comment: Better to persuade them to allocate n + 1 bytes @MartinJames

Comment: fgetc() is reading character by character on a loop that seems slow to me, but your answer is getting to what I really need to find out and that is I want a quick way of loading a file to memory so I want to avoid calling fseek() ftell() and the rewind functions.